# Is there a software that can crawl a webpage, discover all files with a given extension and download them all?

Tags: windows-7, download, download-manager

Is there a software that can crawl a webpage, discover all files with a given extension, and download them all?

It can be a standalone software or a Firefox add-in.

Answer (score 7):

Like... [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/)?
[image: screenshot of DTA]

Comment: Is there a solution for Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: please expand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A web search for "webcrawler or webspider" will being up a large number of other crawlers.
WebReaper will do what you asked for and is not to hard to use.It downloads the whole site and links,if you want.It just depends on how deep you wish to go.The deeper you go the longer it takes and the greater the website bandwidth you use.
http://www.webreaper.net/